# Can I connect to Kerberized Kafka from spark running in another Kerberized Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka, kerberos, keytab

I'm trying to put some records into a Kafka cluster  that is kerberized, from a Spark Process which is running in another Kerberized cluster (different domains). I think the issue is with trying to read a dataset in spark record by record and put them in kafka (as a result of which an active connection needs to be maintained with both clusters). Please help.

I have tried setting the VM property -Djava.security.auth.login.config with a jaas file with the principal and keytab corresponding to the kafka cluster during run time using System.setProperty(), but with no luck.

Before submitting the spark process using spark2-submit, I need to kinit using the keytab corresponding to the Hadoop Cluster in order for the spark process to run.

Comment: _"Domain"_ applies to networking, not to Kerberos. So I assume you are using Active Directory, since it makes a mangled mess of DNS and LDAP and Kerberos services in the same "domain servers".

Comment: If Spark user principal name (UPN) belongs to realm `ALPHA.CORP` and the Kafka brokers service principal names (SPN) belong to realm `BETA.CORP` then **usually** you just have to define in `krb5.conf` the 3 realms `ALPHA.CORP` / `BETA.CORP` / `CORP` ==> on Spark side, the Kerberos client will hop automatically to the root realm to get access to "BETA" realm and obtain a service ticket for Kafka. Assuming all AD realms trust each other. If you don't have trust then you are screwed.